# Get the list of unique elements from multiple list and count of unique elements-column as list in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks something like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['home']=[['us','uk','argentina'], 
                ['denmark','china'], 
                '',
                '',
                ['australia','protugal','chile','russia'],
           ['turkey']]
df["away"] = [['us','mexico'],
            '',
              '',
            ['uk','finland','greece'],
            '',
            ['turkey']]
```

I want to create a column that gives the list of unique elements from the column -home and away and another column that gives the count of unique elements.

Desired output:

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP9Od.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nicoowr: I tried combining both the list, which results in a nested list. On the nested list, I tried flattening it. However, stuck at the flattening bit

df["unique_country"] = df.iloc[:,0:2].values.tolist()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of renaming the third column to unique country, as `row.unique` is already taken.

```
df["unique_country"]=df.apply(lambda row: list(set((row.home if row.home else []) + (row.away if row.away else []))) , axis=1)
df["count_unique"]=df.apply(lambda row: len(row.unique_country),axis=1)
```

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you so much . Say my dataframe has around 19 such columns. What should be a ideal way to run this with 19 columns instead of 2, as shared in the example above.